# Why is the thermodynamic definition of temperature only valid for large systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy

I remember my thermal physics instructor telling me that the definition of temperature, $$\frac{1}{T} \equiv \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{N, V},$$ is only valid for (sufficiently) large systems. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

As a general statement, statistical mechanics is bound to work with finite size systems but its results agree with classical thermodynamics only at the thermodynamic limit. In practice one recovers the usual thermodynamic behavior only for large systems.

For the specific case of the formula for $1/T$, one of the reasons to request a large size of the system is that temperature is an intensive quantity (does not scale with the size of the system) while the microcanonical entropy (the simplest way to get entropy as a function of $U$) becomes extensive only at the thermodynamic limit (see good Statistical Mechanics textbooks for the proof).